# How to find toolstripmenuItem with name

Tags: c#, menustrip, toolstripdropdown, toolstripmenu

I have set visible property of my menuStrip1 items to false as

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem itm in menuStrip1.Items)
{
    itm.Visible = false;
}
```

Now I know the Names of `toolStripMenuItem and dropDownItem` of the menustrip1. How to can I activate the required `toolStripMenuItem and dropDownItem`.

I have

```
string mnItm = "SalesToolStripMenuItem";
string ddItm = "invoiceToolStripMenuItem";
```

Now I want to set visible true to these two(`toolStripMenuItem and dropDownItem`) items. How can I do that? I know those names only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
string strControlVal ="somecontrol"; //"SalesToolStripMenuItem" or "invoiceToolStripMenuItem" in your case
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
{
     if (strControlVal == item.Name)
     { 
        item.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Initialize `strControlVal` string on your discretion where you need it.

Comment: In your code only one `strcontrolval` can be initialized for next one you have to reassign again

Comment: OP can take a string array if he wants.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use those names to get the actual `item` via `MenuStrip.Items` indexer:

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = menuStrip1.Items[mnItm] as ToolStripMenuItem;
ToolStripDropDownMenu ddItem = menuStrip1.Items[ddItm] as ToolStripDropDownMenu;
```

Comment: You just helped me solve a 2 day problem I was trying to wrap my head around -- needed to add the "as ToolStripMenuItem"

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [ToolStripItemCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.find.aspx) method.

```
var items = menustrip.Items.Find("SalesToolStripMenuItem", true);
foreach(var item in items)
{
    item.Visible = false;
}
```

second parameter says whether or not to search the childrens.

Comment: And then how to set the visibility of the found item(s)? Your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @ChocapicSz `foreach(var item in items)item.Visible = true;`

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
menuStrip1.Items[mnItm].Visible = true;
menuStrip1.Items[ddItm].Visible = true;
```

or if you want to set Visible to multiple toolstrip items:

```
string [] visibleItems = new [] {"SalesToolStripMenuItem", "invoiceToolStripMenuItem"};
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
{
     if (visibleItems.Contains(item.Name))
     { 
        item.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: short and concise! I like the oneliner

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question you are trying to disable other than the above two mentioned toolstrip items. Since you know the name of the menu items a slight change in code can get you along

```
  foreach (ToolStripMenuItem itm in menuStrip1.Items)
    {
       if(itm.Text !="SalesToolStripMenuItem" || itm.Text !="invoiceToolStripMenuItem")
        {
         itm.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MenuItemName = sender.ToString()
    }
```