# Why Controls.Find doesn't work with ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#

I am using the following method to access a controls properties via the control name:

```
var ctrl = frm.Controls.Find("textbox1", true).FirstOrDefault();
ctrl.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ctrlperm.Value.ToString());
```

and it is working fine, But it doesn't seem to work with ToolStripMenuItem because when I'm trying to use it with ToolStripMenuItem I get error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

another problem is that when I'm using this code I don't really know the type of the control that i'm dealing with, meaning that it might be a ToolStripMenuItem or any other control, so Is there a unified way to access any control via its name?

Comment: check this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974249/how-to-find-toolstripmenuitem-with-name)

Comment: @Soner Gonul, I can't use "as ToolStripMenuItem" because I don't know the control type when I'm calling it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `ToolStripMenuItem` isn't a `Control`. Every element which inherits from `Control` can be found with the method you use. Try to find the parent element of your `ToolStripMenuItem`, which is a `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Claudio P, what if thee menuItem doesn't have an owner so therefore it has no control.

Comment: This seems more like something that should go in comments than answers.

Comment: I tried to add a comment to his answer but it wouldn't allow

Comment: Ah are you facing this issue?